# Using smartcard through rdp (Raspberry)

Tags: smartcard, rdp

Hi I present my setup and then I show the problems:

Raspberry Pi Model 2 (Client RDP) -----------> Desktop DELL (Server RDP)

SO: Raspbian Wheezy -------------------------> SO: Windows 7

Smartcard reader integrated in DELL Keyboard connected to Raspberry.

Now the problem:
When I use the smartcard reader in the host (Desktop DELL) with the keyboard connected and with DNIe (spanish identity document) introduced in it functions. I can go to my explorer and I see the certificates.

Now I connect to the Raspberry and via RDP I see the screen of the host (Windows 7) in Raspberry's screen. Then I connect the DNIe in the smartcard reader slot but no light is showed in the keyboard. (When I connect it in the host desktop it shows a green signal meaning the card is detected. I also open the explorer in the remote session and don't appear any certificate and I can't sign the test that the State provide us to test the signature with DNIe.

I read a lot of opinions in other websites and everyone says that it's not possible to do that when you are connected via rdp, that's true or there is a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is most likely caused by a built-in feature of winscard.dll library which represents [PC/SC layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC/SC) (low level subsystem providing access to the smartcard readers) in MS Windows. When winscard.dll detects there is an RDP session open, it disables access to the local readers, redirects all calls to the remote client and by doing this it effectively provides access only to the readers connected to the RDP client machine.

I am aware of three solutions that can prevent PC/SC redirection:

1. Don't use RDP. This is the EASIEST, CHEAPEST and CLEANEST solution. Really!
2. Ask your card vendor to replace PC/SC (winscard.dll) in middleware with something else. Good luck with that!
3. **STRONGLY DISCOURAGED:** You can [hack your winscard.dll](http://lifayk.blogspot.ro/2012/07/windows-smart-card-subsystem-and-remote.html) library and disable redirection feature.

Personally I always stick with the first option - easiest, cheapest and cleanest solution.

Comment: thanks for the reply, definitely I won't use RDP.