# Smartcard access on Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, smartcard, smartcard-reader

How do I access a smartcard that is locally attached to a Windows Server 2008R2 in a self written Windows service that is running on that server?

NB: I can access the same smartcard when I start the service as normal Windows 10 application from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not provide enough information about the problem you are experiencing but changing service identity to [LocalService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40113586/c-getslotlist-failing-when-called-from-iis-but-not-from-iis-express) and not using [RDP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36774892/using-smartcard-through-rdp-raspberry) usually helps.

Comment: Our actual problem was not this (although the RDP issue complicated remote analysis to the point that we installed VNC), but a combination of an unactivated smartcard (we didn't know that in the beginning) , wrong registry settings and that we were not able to test with the smartcard in VirtualBox.