# Is where a way to stop windows Smart Card service from redirecting to local computer when using RDP?

Tags: windows, windows-services, smartcard, windows-server-2012

We have dongle server what allow us to use them in differen VM servers (we use VMWare). 
We connected some dongles to VM Windows 2012 server. If we use VWare terminal to connetc to server we can see all the dongles and our software can work with them with no problems. 
But if we connecting to server via RDP all dongles stop working.
Even if we turn off smart card sharing in RDP options.

As stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/smart-cards/smart-card-and-remote-desktop-services) this is default behaviour of Smart Card service with RDP. 
But we dont want crash our app behaviour then someone want to do some some maintainance on this server.
Is where a way to handle this rather than turning RDP connection off?

Comment: See my [older answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36775405/3325704).